# Cant bind the Master page to my Page

Tags: asp.net

I'm new in ASP.Net and I want to creat a very simple form which bind to a master page but no success. this is my Master Page code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" /> 
</head>
<body>
<form runat=server>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
  <body>
   <table width=100% border=1 style="background:black" >
    <tr>
      <td width=20%></td>
      <td width=80%><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
      <td width=20%></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </body>
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and code of my page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID=HeadContent runat=server>
</asp:Content>   

<asp:Content ID="MainContent" runat=server ContentPlaceHolderID=MainContent >
</asp:Content>
```

but hte table in the Master Page doesn't appear in the page.Would you please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID=HeadContent runat=server>
</asp:Content>   

<asp:Content ID="MainContent" runat=server ContentPlaceHolderID=MainContent >
</asp:Content>
```

is entirely wrong.

The `DOCTYPE` should be listed in the master. Secondly:

```
<asp:Content ID="HContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="MainContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" >
</asp:Content>
```

Would more closely match your intent. But one flaw in your style, as it were, and this is strictly a style thing:

```
<asp:Content ID="HContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server" >
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" >
</asp:Content>
```

Notice how I put `runat="server"` at the end, on both tags? Always put that at the end, it'll make it easier to make sure you've put it in the right place. Alternately, always put it right before `ID`

---

### Edit:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
  <body>
   <table width=100% border=1 style="background:black" >
    <tr>
      <td width=20%></td>
      <td width=80%><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
      <td width=20%></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </body>
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Where you have this in the master page, the contents of the `ContentPlaceHolder` won't be shown when a child page implements this section. You'll need to move those outside of the master page `ContentPlaceHolder` declaration. This concept is very "either or" and there is no room to have an alternate opinion. It was written this way on purpose.

Perhaps you want:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
<body>
 <table width=100% border=1 style="background:black" >
  <tr>
    <td width=20%></td>
    <td width=80%><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
    <td width=20%></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
```

Comment: I did it but still cant see the Table which is in Master Page in my Page

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot to address that part!

Comment: thnk you for your answer,but why we need contentplaceholder?

Comment: I truly don't understand what you're asking? It's so that we can have a master page with sections "this is where the content goes" and then the sub pages only have to focus on the content. It's a form of code-reuse and inheritance. There's no reason to include `<html>` tag at the top of every page, they will always be there on all IIS responses. So we put those "common" elements in one Master page, and then each "content" page is just what we need to render this one page.

Comment: I meant th contentplaceholder plays no Role here?

Comment: I don't understand. It has to be told where in the page to be placed. That means putting a self-closed `<tag />` tag in the page. That way the framework knows where to put the `content` from later on.

Comment: ahaaan,ok ok now I understand

Answer (score 2):

Are you specifying the master page in your @Page directive?

For example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Master1.master" Title="Content Page"%>
```